# splitting packages into multiple files

Tags: packages

I am writing a package, which is growing very rapidly.

I would like to split into multiple files, and so I thought for example, that I could define all my counters in a separate file.

```
\input{mycounters}
```

or

```
\usepackage{mycounters}
```

So this is my first question: which one should I use and why?

But I'd rather use the `input` syntax because that way, I could do the following:

```
\input{./style/mycounters}
```

And thus separate my *style latex files* into a new directory.

But for some reason, it's not working.

Any advice?

Comment: Look at packages like `babel` or `glossaries` or `biblatex`. All of these load extra files.

Comment: If `mycounters` could also be (used as) a stand-alone package, then it might make sense to use `\usepackage`. If it can only be used as part of your bigger package, `\input` seems slightly more sensible. AFAIK the `\input` path is not relative to the file that contains it, but instead relative to the LaTeX call. If your package lives in a directory searched by `kpathsea`, then `\input{mycounters}` should work whether the file lives in a subdirectory or not. Of course this requires that you choose a unique name unlikely to clash with user-decided file names of their own projects.

Comment: If any of the sub-packages can be loaded separately, and all require `mycounters`, you might consider `\RequirePackage{...}` that doesn't repeat loading if the package is already loaded.

Comment: Typically one places each \chapter in a separate file using \include then selects which one to work on using \includeonly.  This allows \ref to work across files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `myclass.cls`, you can include `mypackage.sty` files:

Inside `myclass.cls`:

```
\ProvidesClass{myclass}

\usepackage{mypackage}
```

Inside `mypackage.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage.sty}

\newcommand{...}{...}
```